# Why Maven resolver causes management dependencies errors?

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian

I have a project and 2 development environments, 1 on Windows and 1 on Linux.
So everything works on Windows, but not on Linux.

In my POM, I defined the management dependences, like this :

```
    <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
              <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
              <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-all</artifactId>
              <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
              <type>pom</type>
              <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
           ......
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I use Arquillian to run my unit tests and the deployment method loads the dependences from the POM :

```
PomEquippedResolveStage pom = Maven.resolver().offline().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");
WebArchive arch =
            ShrinkWrap
                    .create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
.....
.addAsLibraries(pom.importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile());
```

But, the loadPomFromFile method throw an InvalidConfigurationFileException :

> [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failed to resolve POM for org.wildfly.bom:jboss-javaee-7.0-with-all:8.2.0.Final due to The
>   repository system is offline but the artifact
>   org.wildfly.bom:jboss-javaee-7.0-with-all:pom:8.2.0.Final is not
>   available in the local repository. @
>   com.my.package:my.projet:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   /home/workspace/My_projet/pom.xml

Obviously, all management dependencies are not resolved, why?

Comment: Is your linux environment behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, but also Windows ! I verified, these dependencies are in my local repository

Comment: @Seb: Maven says they are not in your local repo. Make sure that you and Maven agree in which paths it should search for the dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says that Maven would like to download the dependency from somewhere since it can't be found in your local repo. You also configure Maven to work offline, so it has no way to solve the problem and it fails.

The problem is probably that you configure Maven in your tests to look in a special local test repo instead of the default `$HOME/.m2/repository/`.

To fix the problem, make sure that Maven looks in the place where you expect it to look.